Add negative padding to a view to offset a parent view
I have the following component
Doesnt work
<View>               // paddingHorizontal of 16 here
    <ScrollView>     // no style added here
        <View>       // marginHorizontal of -16 here
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</View

When i have it set up like above, my inner view does not extend the width of my device. However when i pull my view outside of scroll view, it works as i expect (the outer view's padding is offset)
Works as expected
<View>               // paddingHorizontal of 16 here
    <View>           // marginHorizontal of -16 here
    </View>
    <ScrollView>     // no style added here
    </ScrollView>
</View

Problem is i need the view in the scroll view lol.
RN version is "react-native": "0.73.6",
Thanks in advance
